# Get a rectangle of a newly added ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

I add a new record to a ListView's ItemsSource collection:

```
Source.Add(newRecord);
```

After this action I'm trying to get the rectangle of the corresponding item:

```
ListViewItem newItem = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newRecord) as ListViewItem;
Rect rc = LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(newItem);
```

But, unfortunately, `rc` is (0, 0, 0, 0). Is seems like when I call the GetLayoutSlot method, new ListViewItem is not yet arranged. How can I obtain the correct information directly after adding a new record?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `list.UpdateLayout();` before the line `ListViewItem newItem = ...` should help to get the rectangle immediately.

But generally, I would not recommend to use `UpdateLayout()` anywhere in a WPF program. The layout procedures in WPF are asynchronous for performance reasons. Therefore, it probably would be better if your program determined the rectangles of the list items at a later point in time.

Here is what I mean with "later point in time":

```
Source.Add(newRecord);

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,
    new Action(() =>
    {
        ListViewItem newItem = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newRecord) as ListViewItem;
        Rect rc = LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(newItem);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("rc = " + rc);
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! DispatcherPriority.Loaded - nice, very nice :)